# mysql match X number of row column value with another column in same table

Tags: php, mysql

Hi doesn't mean to be rude but i'm new to mysql

Table : info 
Column : id,squad_1,squad_2,squad_12_result,squad_3,squad_4,squad_34_result

```
id  squad_1 squad_2 squad_12_result squad_3 squad_4 squad_34_result
--- ------- ------- --------------- ------- ------- ---------------
10     a       b          win          g        l          win
9      a       c          win          g        m          lose
8      a       d          draw         g        n          win
7      a       e          lose         g        o          win
6      a       f          win          g        p          draw
5      a       g          win          g        q          lose
4      a       h          win          g        r          win
3      a       i          draw         g        s          win
2      a       j          lose         g        t          lose
1      a       k          win          g        u          draw
```

what i want to achieve is latest 5 rows of 'squad_12_result' column match with entire rows of 'squad_34_result'

which mean the output result will be like

```
id  squad_1 squad_2 squad_12_result | id  squad_3 squad_4 squad_34_result
--- ------- ------- --------------- | --- ------- ------- ---------------
10     a       b          win       | 8     g        n          win
9      a       c          win       | 7     g        o          win
8      a       d          draw      | 6     g        p          draw
7      a       e          lose      | 5     g        q          lose
6      a       f          win       | 4     g        r          win
```

is there any way to achieve it? any advice are welcome

---

i seems to be able to match the result from both column by running this query

```
        SELECT * 
        FROM `info` 
        WHERE squad_12_result
        LIKE squad_34_result
```

which only return

```
id  squad_1 squad_2 squad_12_result squad_3 squad_4 squad_34_result
--- ------- ------- --------------- ------- ------- ---------------
10     a       b          win          g        l          win
4      a       h          win          g        r          win
2      a       j          lose         g        t          lose
```

is there any work around to match the "squad_12_result"

```
id  squad_1 squad_2 squad_12_result
--- ------- ------- ---------------
10     a       b          win         
9      a       c          win         
8      a       d          draw        
7      a       e          lose      
6      a       f          win
```

with "squad_34_result" ?

```
id  squad_3 squad_4 squad_34_result
--- ------- ------- ---------------
8     g        n          win
7     g        o          win
6     g        p          draw
5     g        q          lose
4     g        r          win
```

basically it's compare the latest "5" rows of "squad_12_result" with entire rows of "squad_34_result" as you can see it's matching the result column

the ideal output will be something like this

```
id  squad_1 squad_2 squad_12_result | id  squad_3 squad_4 squad_34_result
--- ------- ------- --------------- | --- ------- ------- ---------------
10     a       b          win       | 8     g        n          win
9      a       c          win       | 7     g        o          win
8      a       d          draw      | 6     g        p          draw
7      a       e          lose      | 5     g        q          lose
6      a       f          win       | 4     g        r          win
```

Comment: "latest" usually means "most recent". you seem to have the OLDEST records in your output.

Comment: Hi Marc i just re-edit my question. thanks for your reply

Comment: I suggest you add a date/time stamp column and then GROUP/ORDER by those and LIMIT it to a certain number. It will make your life a lot simpler.

Comment: Hi Fred, thank you for your reply, 
yes there's a date for every squad match in this format "31/05/15" i doesn't include it in question cause i personally think that it only matching the value in both column

Comment: Wrong to put data into columns. Data should be in rows.

Comment: *"in this format "31/05/15""* - You should be using MySQL's built-in date/datetime functions for this and not storing them as varchar. Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: middlestump's right. Normalise your schema.

Comment: Hi Fred, thank you for your reply again.
basically the data that store under each column came from certain website. i'm using python ( scrapy + selenium ) to scrape the entire website data and store it under mysql. for now i'll just need to match the latest "5" rows of "squad_12_result" with "squad_34_result" which similar like the output that i drafted above.

thats the ideal output that i wish to achieve. is it possible to do it with my current structure?

Comment: Hi Middlestump and strawberry, thanks for your info.

to be honest i'm a fresh guy in mysql. possible lead me to the right direction? Thanks !